# Not able to extract all values of a column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am having problem extracting values from a mysql table:
I need to get all values of picname column from a table where uid condition is satisfied.
Now i have two rows where this condition is satisfied but i am getting output only for 1st case. I am not able to get the second row's value. 1st rows value repeats again for second time.

```
$i = 0;
for($i;$i<2;$i++)
{
    $s = "SELECT picname FROM uploaded_data WHERE uid='$uid'";
    $que = mysql_query($s,$db);
    while($num = mysql_fetch_array($que))
    {

    echo $name ['picname'];

    }

}
```

Thank You

Comment: after while loop set free `$que`  like this :
`mysql_free_result($que);`

Comment: `$name ['picname']` should be `$num['picname']`. Is that just a typo here?

Comment: Where do you change the value of `$uid`? It runs the same query in every loop. BTW you should write a query like this: `select picname FROM uploaded_data WHERE uid in ($uids)` and iterate over the query results.

Comment: Yaa..sorry...it is $num instead of $name...but still it is not working

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should not give you any result you do not have

```
$name
```

should be:

```
$i = 0;
for($i;$i<2;$i++)
{
    $s = "SELECT picname FROM uploaded_data WHERE uid='$uid'";
    $que = mysql_query($s,$db);
    while($num = mysql_fetch_array($que))
    {

    echo $num['picname'];

    }
   mysql_free_result($que);

}
```